# Android Security Pattern

Tags: android, security

I want to create a custom screen lock (more precisely a Pattern, like the one that's activated in Settings -> Security -> Screen lock and then selecting Pattern). I have been searching a while and found nothing about it and don't know if even it is possible.

Is it possible?.

Comment: security for what? your app? the users? what you want to secure?

Comment: can you be more specific as which security pattern u r talking about ?

Comment: ok, sorry, just edited the question. I was talking about the screen lock pattern (the one that's activated in Settings->Security->Screen lock->Pattern).

Comment: Yes, sort of. HTC has an SDK for making your own lock screen on their devices (I hear, they will make it soon backwards compatible). It's also possible to make screen locks on non-HTC non-rooted android phones, those applications do exist and they seem to be getting good reviews, but it's just a hassle for their developers because those apps make use of undocumented features and you have to evolve your code every time Android updates those undocumented APIs. So if you're just a beginner, I'd suggest you stay away from that, or at least just make a screen lock for HTC phones or rooted phones.

Comment: Also, take a look at some of the last keynote Google IO videos. I wasn't really paying attention, but I think I saw a Jellybeans demo that showed that now the screen lock could be customized. I just don't know how customizable, and whatever they allow us to do with the screen lock on Jellybeans, I doubt that it will be back-ported to the previous APIs anytime soon, so that may not be a viable option for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible to create a lock screen. Source code for Android's pattern lock: [LockPatternUtils.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/HEAD/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/LockPatternUtils.java). Recent discussion talking about some of the problems of LockPatternUtils.java: [How Salt value for hashing of user's PIN/password generated?](http://groups.google.com/group/android-security-discuss/browse_thread/thread/2eca2318d3daa56c). There was a discussion of using third party lock screens to relieve the long password requirement when using EFS (see [Full device encryption and excessive password typing](http://groups.google.com/group/android-security-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1b8379a41adeca13)).

[Android Security Discussions](http://groups.google.com/group/android-security-discuss) would be a good place to ask in a format that does not get you down voted. Stack Overflow is not a good place for "book recommendations," "implementation recommendations" and other open ended questions since there is no right answer (and you can't give points for the correct answer).

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is very much ambiguous.

If you want create a custom lock screen (that's I assume from 'security pattern') then you will need to create a custom home screen application that should have its own lock/unlock mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I use a vault app that has an extremely secure password that utilizes operators. It's easy to remember and impossible to crack. It doesn't lock the entire device, but you can store your important info in the vault.

It was free and definitely worth the download: http://www.itsmesecurity.com/its-me-mobile

Comment: "It's easy to remember and impossible to crack" - that sounds like a challenge ;)